# Sidekiq worker not getting queued in testing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sidekiq, minitest

I am using sidekiq to queue a job to validate the input of a field on a model (a link) and visit the link to make sure it doesn't return a 404 if it passes a regex validation.

If the regex validation passes and the link does not return 404 I assign another attribute to the same model but on a different field.

The worker is trigger by calling a method, the method is triggered after an `after_commit, on: :update` callback

The method only triggers the worker if 'previous_changes['json object I am using to make changes']' is true. This is so the worker won't continue to be called over and over again.

All of this works fine in development, confirmed with multiple use cases by QA'ing it myself

I am trying to write a test in MiniTest to ensure that a worker gets queued when the model's json field is changed but a worker is not being queued and for the life of me I can't figure out why.

I am testing the expectations for the worker being queued with:

```
assert_difference 'WorkerClass.jobs.size' do
  site = sites(:site_from_fixtures)
  site.attribute_that_triggers_change = { "random" => "json_object" }
  site.save
end
```

The test returns: "Expected: 1, Actual: 0"

Any input would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Tried using `save!` just for kicks to see if it's possibly a validation error (I should get a different failure message then expected: 1, actual: 0 if it were a validation issue), and didn't work :/
If I update the same record in the same way in the rails console (loading the console with RAILS_ENV=test rails c) the worker runs in sidekiq... What is happening here?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue was fixed by installing the [test_after_commit](https://github.com/grosser/test_after_commit) gem.

Apparently after_commit's don't fire in tests unless you either use that gem or specify the necessary changes in a test_helper. I opted for the gem option just to keep things a little easier.